# Variation Subsites Not Created - all timers finish in 00:00:00

Tags: timer-jobs, variations

Part 1:

Variations Create Hierarchies Job Definition successfully creates the source & target labels.

After that no subsites are created on the target labels nor any target pages.

I've created a new site collection to test and still can't get this working so I'd conclude this is a problem with the farm.

I have run the variationsfixuptool, which says it's starting the timer jobs.

Moreover if I look in Job History of timer jobs every timer job in the entire web application for the past day has succeeded in 0:00:00 window.

Part 2 (cont'd)

If you manually spawn the variation site using site manager the variation sites are created (but not their subsites).